# yii2 queue перезапускает всю очередь вместо конкретного сообщения

Tags: yii2, очередь, rabbitmq

Пытаюсь реализовать очередь на  rabbitmq в Yii2 используя стандартную [yii2-queue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/docs/guide/driver-amqp-interop.md)

Допустим в очереди есть сообщения 1, 2, 3, 4 и если в каком-то из сообщений возникает ошибка (например 3) мы не выкидываем исключение, а снова выполняем 3 пока обработка не будет успешной. Например:

1(done), 2(done), 3 (err), 3 (err), 3(done), 4(done) ...

Использовал события как описано тут https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/docs/guide/retryable.md

```
$this->on(self::EVENT_AFTER_ERROR, function (ExecEvent $event) {
    $event->retry = true;
});

...

if ($response->isFail) {
    $queue->trigger(Queue::EVENT_AFTER_ERROR);
}
...
```

но судя по сообщениям в терминале rabbit перезапускает не 1 сообщение а всю очередь и выходит вот такая какаха

```
1 - done
2 - done
3 - err
1 - done
2 - done
3 - done
4 - err
1 - done
2 - done
...
```

никак не могу найти адекватное решение этой проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу всего кода, но подозреваю что проблема в том, что вы вешаете общий обработчик на всю очередь, который заставляет все задания запускаться повторно:

```php
$this->on(self::EVENT_AFTER_ERROR, function (ExecEvent $event) {
    $event->retry = true;
});
```

Для повтора лучше пользовать исключения и интерфейс `RetryableJobInterface`. Он именно так и задумывался, чтобы индивидуально задавать логику повтора под каждое конкретное задание.

Можно и через события, но тогда вам нужно как минимуим проверять тип задания внутри обработчика.